# Negroni and Gorilla Context ClearHandler

Tags: go, gorilla, negroni

Is is possible to use [Gorilla's](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context) `context.ClearHandler()` as middleware for Negroni like I've seen it used as middleware for Alice? Something like:

```
n.Use(context.ClearHandler())
```

At the moment I'm calling `context.Clear(r)` after every response but I would prefer the tidying up to be taken care of automatically. I'm currently getting the following error:

```
cannot use context.ClearHandler() (type http.Handler) as type negroni.Handler in argument to n.Use:                                                                   
http.Handler does not implement negroni.Handler (wrong type for ServeHTTP method)                                                                                                  
  have ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)                                                                                                                         
  want ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, http.HandlerFunc)
```

But I'm not sure what the error message is telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Negroni.Use()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/negroni#Negroni.Use) expects a parameter of type [`negroni.Handler`](http://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/negroni#Handler) but Gorilla's [`context.ClearHandler()`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gorilla/context#ClearHandler) returns a value of type [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/).

Good thing is that there is an alternative [`Negroni.UseHandler()`](http://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/negroni#Negroni.UseHandler) method which expects an `http.Handler` so just use that. Note that `context.ClearHandler()` also expects another `http.Handler`:

```
otherHandler := ... // Other handler you want to clear
n.UseHandler(context.ClearHandler(otherHandler))
```

#### Notes:

The [`Router`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router) from the [`gorilla/mux`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux) package automatically calls [`context.Clear()`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gorilla/context#Clear) at the end of a request lifetime, so if you are using it you don't need to clear the context using `context.ClearHandler()`. You only need to use it for other / custom handlers (unless you want to call `context.Clear()` manually).

Comment: Thanks but getting: `not enough arguments in call to context.ClearHandler`

Comment: @tommyd456 Yes, updated the answer. `context.ClearHandler()` also expects another `http.Handler`.

Comment: So I can do away with my `n.UseHandler(router)` and simply add `n.UseHandler(context.ClearHandler(router))` ?

Comment: @tommyd456 Please see edited answer. If you are using `mux.Router`, that automatically clears at the end of requests lifetime, so you don't need to use `context.ClearHandler()` at all. You only need to use it for other/custom handlers (unless you want to call `context.Clear()` manually).

Comment: I should have mentioned - I'm using httprouter by Julien Schmidt